# Adobe Air - Sending pre-populated SMS via Android

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, adobe

I'm trying to send a pre-populated SMS via AS3 in Adobe AIR. It works perfectly on iOS,  with the native SMS UI displaying with the pre-populated text. However on Android it's seeing the whole string as the phone number, showing the following error -

> Invalid recipients(s): <0123456789&body=Hey! This is a test message.
>   http://google.com>

The code I'm using -

```
var number:String = "0123456789"
var callURL:String="sms:"+number+"&body=Hey! This is a test message. http://google.com";
var targetURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest(callURL);
NavigateToURL(targetURL)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st) The `&` that you are using should be an `?`

```
sms:+15105550101?body=hello%20there
```

Refer to [RFC 5724](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5724) for details.

**Note:** on iOS8+ the `&` is correct, for iOS7 and under use an `;`

2nd) Certain Android versions are just plain broken when it comes to including a 'body' in an SMS URI. You would need to look up the 'buggy' versions in Google's bug database.